# Behavior of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^n}{n}z^{n(n+1)}}$ at the boundary

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I have to study the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^n}{n}z^{n(n+1)}}$. I proved that the radius of convergence is $1$ but now I'm having troubles with the behavior at the boundary. I know that it converges when $z=1,-1$ as the resulting series is the alternate harmonic and at $z=i,-i$ by the Dirichlet criterion. What should I do to study all the other points in the boundary?